# subsequent IF statement: shorter ways to assign values to parameters based on another variable value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement, search

I want to create an array in which the values depends on one variables and two coefficients. The coefficient values depend on the variable value as well. A simple example:

```
x_intervals = [2, 10]
C1_values = [0.1, 0.5, -0.2]
C2_values = [0.4,0.6, -0.8]
```

Here I want C1 and C2:

- to be equal to the first array element if x<2 (so C1 = 0.1 and C2 = 0.4)
- to be equal to the second array element if x>2 and x>10 (so C1 = 0.5 and C2 = 0.6)
- to be equal to the third element if x>10 (so C1 = -0.2 and C2 = -0.8)

Then I want to use these coefficients to find the values of y=C1*x^C2 for any number of x contained in a list.

Currently I do this using subsequent if functions as:

```
x = [0.1,1,1.5,2.2,5,9,12,20,30,60,70,100]
y = []
for x_ in x:
   if x_<=x_intervals[0]:
      C1 = C1_values[0]
      C2 = C2_values[0]
   elif x_<=x_intervals[1]:
      C1 = C1_values[1]
      C2 = C2_values[1]
   else:
     C1 = C1_values[2]
     C2 = C2_values[2]
   y.append(C1*x_ **C2)
```

This works but it is extremely dirty and manual, and if I increase the number of intervals it becomes extremely long to code.
I am sure that there is a smarter and cleaner way to do this.

Any idea? Thanks in advance

(Using Python, but this is more of a logic/algorithm question)

####################################################################
EDIT:
Thank you all for your solutions. They all worked and are useful
I found the numpy solution using searchsorted the most appropriate in my case.
The code looks like this now (where Coeff_1 and Coeff_2 are two pandas dataframe where I store my coefficients C1 and C2):

```
def calculate_curve_value(Re=10, df=pd.DataFrame()):
    MaxRe = df.loc["MaxRe"].values
    C1 = df.loc["C1"].values
    C2 = df.loc["C2"].values
    
    idx = np.searchsorted(MaxRe, Re)
    value = C1[idx]*Re**(C2[idx])
    
    return value

Re = [0.1,1,1.5,2.2,5,9,12,20,30,60,70,100]
N = []
f = []
for i in Re:
    N.append(calculate_curve_value(Re=i, df=Coeff_1))
    f.append(calculate_curve_value(Re=i, df=Coeff_2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would make a lot of sense to use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) here.

What you want is a [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) on `x_intervals`, then a vectorial operation:

```
import numpy as np

x_intervals = np.array([2, 10])
C1_values = np.array([0.1, 0.5, -0.2])
C2_values = np.array([0.4,0.6, -0.8])

x = [0.1,1,1.5,2.2,5,9,12,20,30,60,70,100]

idx = np.searchsorted(x_intervals, x)
y = C1_values[idx]*x**C2_values[idx]
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.03981072,  0.1       ,  0.1176079 ,  0.80246041,  1.3132639 ,
        1.86859641, -0.02739586, -0.01820564, -0.01316234, -0.00755978,
       -0.00668269, -0.00502377])
```

If you really want to use pure python, go with [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html):

```
from bisect import bisect_left

x_intervals = [2, 10]
C1_values = [0.1, 0.5, -0.2]
C2_values = [0.4,0.6, -0.8]

x = [0.1,1,1.5,2.2,5,9,12,20,30,60,70,100]

y = []
for x_ in x:
    idx = bisect_left(x_intervals, x_)
    y.append(C1_values[idx]*x_**C2_values[idx])
```

Output:

```
[0.03981071705534973, 0.1, 0.11760790225246737, 0.8024604053351734, 1.3132639022018835, 1.8685964094232759, -0.027395863825287095, -0.0182056420302608, -0.013162336572232132, -0.007559777184220181, -0.006682693821222914, -0.005023772863019159]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. The numpy solution worked just perfectly for me. Clean and easy!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
x_intervals = [2, 10]
C1_values = [0.1, 0.5, -0.2]
C2_values = [0.4, 0.6, -0.8]
x = [0.1, 1, 1.5, 2.2, 5, 9, 12, 20, 30, 60, 70, 100]
y = []
for x_ in x:
    i = next(
        (i for i, interval in enumerate(x_intervals) if x_ <= interval),
        len(C1_values) - 1,
    )
    C1 = C1_values[i]
    C2 = C2_values[i]
    y.append(C1 * x_**C2)

print(y)
```

This has the same logic as your `if` statement, but it will work if you add additional values to `x_intervals` (as long as the length of `C1_values` and `C2_values` is always `len(x_intervals) + 1`).

We're using [`next` with a default](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to return either the index of the first value in `x_intervals` that is greater than `x_`, or the index of the last value in the `*_values` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Variable names containing an index (like `C1`) are always an indicator that you maybe want to use a `list`. The relationship between your variables `x_interval`, `C1_values` and `C2_values` suggests an associative data structure.

Just to give you a rough idea how the code could look, I re-wrote your code. A `dict` is used that contains upper bounds of x as keys and the respective coefficients `C1` and `C2` as a `list`. I.e. the `coeff` is to be read as `{"upper x": [C1, C2], ...}`.
I wrapped everything in a function just because it seemed more convenient to do so.

Adding more intervals is simply done by adding a line to `coeff`.

```py
def get_coefficients(x):
    coeff = {
            2.: [0.1, 0.4],
            10.: [0.5, 0.6],
            10000.: [-0.2, -0.8]
        }
    for upper, values in coeff.items():
        if x <= upper:
            return (values[0], values[1])
    return (values[0], values[1])


y = []
for x in [0.1, 1, 1.5, 2.2, 5, 9, 12, 20, 30, 60, 70, 100]:
    c = get_coefficients(x)
    y.append(c[0]*x ** c[1])

print(y)
```

The code above could still use some tweaking, e.g. to account for negative numbers.